# Sort files according to Numerical value of filename in Python

Tags: python

I am generating a list of files in a directory and I want them to be sorted according to numerical value in the filename.

Files:

```
0.png
1.png
2.png
...
11.png
12.png
```

and so on

If I generate the list using os.listdir() and then invoke the .sort() method on the list, it looks like shown below:

```
['0.png', '1.png', '10.png', '11.png', '12.png', '13.png', '14.png', '15.png', '16.png', '17.png', '18.png', '19.png', '2.png', '20.png', '21.png', '22.png', '23.png', '24.png', '25.png', '26.png', '3.png', '4.png', '5.png', '6.png', '7.png', '8.png', '9.png']
```

How can I sort it according to numerical value of the name?

On Windows OS, in the Windows Explorer if I sort by the column name in the Details view, it sorts the way I want it to. Can this be done with Python as well?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the builtin [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) function and supply a `key`.

Below the `key` is a function that converts the first part of the filename (before the `'.'`) to an integer. The sort order uses the results of those function calls but actually sorts the original objects.

```
l = ['0.png', '1.png', '10.png', '11.png', '12.png', '13.png', '14.png', '15.png', '16.png', '17.png', '18.png', '19.png', '2.png', '20.png', '21.png', '22.png', '23.png', '24.png', '25.png', '26.png', '3.png', '4.png', '5.png', '6.png', '7.png', '8.png', '9.png']

sorted(l, key=lambda fname: int(fname.split('.')[0]))
```

returns

```
['0.png', '1.png', '2.png', ..., '26.png']
```

Comment: That's really cool! Thanks.